# material UI: How to make the textfield to fit the size of placeholder

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let el = document.getElementById("standard-basic");
    console.log("Initial", el);
  }, 50);
  return (
    <Box p={1}>
      <TextField
        sx={{
          "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
            color: "red"
          }
        }}
        variant="outlined"
        label="Your custom label"
        placeholder="Placeholder Text hahjhkjerh jhejr kjhejrh kjhasdh hjsadh "
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        inputProps={{
          sx: {
            "&::placeholder": {
              color: "green",
              
            },
            width: "fit-content"
          }
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the full-width prop?

Answer (score 0):

```
  const placeholder = 'Placeholder Text hahjhkjerh jhejr kjhejrh kjhasdh hjsadh '

      <TextField
        placeholder={placeholder}
        inputProps={{
          size: placeholder.length,
        }}
      />
```